# How to forward emails to PHP script?

Tags: php, procmail, email-forwarding, fetchmail

I'm trying to figure out how I can forward (or pipe) an email to a PHP script using [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/). I've never done this and am not even sure if I'm on the right track. From what I've read I think I need to use an MDA to forward the mail. I'm using [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) as my MDA.

Here is my fetcmailrc file

```
set daemon 150
set logfile /local/web/sites/sitename/mail/fetchmail.log
poll blahblah with proto IMAP
user Username there with password userpassword is Username here
ssl
fetchall
no rewrite
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d Username -f %F -d %T $HOME/.procmailrc";
```

Here is my procmailrc file. You can see at the bottom I'm trying to pipe the email to a PHP script.

```
SHELL=/bin/csh
DEFAULT=/var/mail/Username/ 
MAILDIR=/var/mail/Username/    

:0
! `/usr/local/bin/php -f /local/web/sites/stack/htdocs/bin/catchmail.php`
```

I run fetchmail and the fowarding (piping to PHP) doesn't work. My fetchmail.log says:

```
procmail:  Insufficient prvileges
procmail:  Unknown user
```

Any pointers? Am I even headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You are not piping to PHP, you are sending email to the address that your PHP script outputs.  You probably want to change the exclamation mark (`!`) to a pipe (`|`) in order for the recipe to do what you describe.

The error message from Procmail indicates that you are invoking it incorrectly, or that it lacks a setuid bit or something like that.  I'm no Fetchmail expert but the `mda` line looks fishy -- you hardly want two conflicting `-d` flags at the very least.  Maybe that's the problem right there.  The path to the `.procmailrc` will be deduced by Procmail with the `-d` option.  Try with something simpler, like this:

```
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T"
```

By the way, the assignment `SHELL=/bin/csh` seems really out of line.  In my experience, attempting to use `csh` or `tcsh` with Procmail simply doesn't work.  (Anyway, read [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).)  If you know exactly what you are doing, please explain why you have it there.  Otherwise, take it out before you do anything else.